# Python Prompt Toolkit: How to always open/show autocompleter?

Tags: python, prompt-toolkit

I use `prompt_toolkit` to ask the user for some input:

```py
from prompt_toolkit import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter

prompt('Input: ', completer=WordCompleter(['abc', 'def', 'xyz']))
```

Is it possible to show the suggestions automatically without any user intervention (no tab key)?

[image: example]

Comment: why to suggest anything when input is empty? Usually autocompleter need 3 chars to open but probably you would change it. But without any char it may try to suggest too many elements. I would rather display suggestion before `Input` and then user could write what it need.

Comment: probably you will have to create own completer instead of `WordCompleter` - and you will have to create own `get_completions()` - see source code [Completer.get_completions()](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/completion/base.py#L169) and [WordCompleter.get_completions()](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/completion/word_completer.py#L52)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pre_run`](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/reference.html#prompt_toolkit.application.Application.run) hook to prompt it.

```
from prompt_toolkit.application.current import get_app

def prompt_autocomplete():
    app = get_app()
    b = app.current_buffer
    if b.complete_state:
        b.complete_next()
    else:
        b.start_completion(select_first=False)

prompt(pre_run=prompt_autocomplete)
```